# Regex to replace integer separated by space

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm creating a MTG card generator with JS, and I was wondering how I would go about replacing my Integers in the card cost using regex? (more for learning than publishing)

card_cost is just a input text value from a user, I want to be able to separate the integers with spaces IE: user enters: "10 1 2" Ints should get replaced but spaces should be kept.

would start like this:

```
if(card_cost)
{
card_cost=card_cost.replace(/INTEGER/g,"<span class='card_costnum' src='numsymbol.png' ></span>");
}
```

The attempt here is to replace the integers with themselves held inside a span to display a background image per number.

Now that I have had time to think about this I'm assuming I'll need to get an array of the integers so I can pass them back through within a span, replacing wont be enough to catch more than one integer correctly I assume.

Comment: Okay, why are you replacing the numbers with a span that includes the same string you're trying to remove numbers from?

Comment: do you mean you want to replace the numbers with the image of that number???

Comment: The point of this is to replace the integers with a span that has a class to put a background image behind the integers that are in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript `replace` function, `$&` refers to the search string itself, so you can write

```
someStr = "12 34 foo 5 bar"
someStr.replace(/\d+/g, "<span whatever>$&</span>")
```

returns

```
<span whatever>12</span> <span whatever>34</span> foo <span whatever>5</span> bar
```

To replace each digit individually, just remove `+`:

```
someStr = "12 34 foo 5 bar"
someStr.replace(/\d/g, "<span whatever>$&</span>")
```

returns

```
 <span whatever>1</span><span whatever>2</span> etc
```

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I'm looking for in your first example, I'm going to test it out real quick.

Comment: This worked great for me, I have a question though, is there a way to regex replace spaces with nothing and not remove empty html objects (such as an image tag)?

Comment: @Event_Horizon: to remove spaces, `str.replace(/\s+/g, '')`. The second part is unclear to me, could you post a new question about this, with examples of input and desired output?

Answer (score 1):

To remove all numeric characters:

```
if(card_cost)
{
    card_cost=card_cost.replace(/\d/g,'');
}
```

But, as noted in the comments, I had no idea why that `span` was in the `replace()`, so I removed it and now what the above does is match numbers, and removes them, replacing them with an empty, zero-character, string.

---

**Edited** following clarification about the intent of the question:

```
if(card_cost)
{
    card_cost = card_cost.replace(/(\d)/g,function(a,b){
        return '<span class="card_costnum" src="numsymbol.png">' + a + '</span>';
    });
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NZ8Hv/3/).

The above will wrap *all* matched numbers in the `span`, but it will match *all* numeric characters.

```
if(card_cost)
{
    card_cost=card_cost.replace(/\b(\d+)\b/g,function(a,b){
        return '<span class="card_costnum" src="numsymbol.png">' + a + '</span>';
    });
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NZ8Hv/2/).

This version will match word-boundary bounded sequences (of one, or more) numeric characters and wrap those matches in `span`s.

References:

- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: The span was there because I am using the class to add a background behind the integers, I'm going to replace them with themselves held inside a span.

Comment: If only you'd asked that in the question... *reworking* Oh, and what format do you want that `span` to take if the number is `9` for example?

Comment: No 0 padding or anything fancy, just the integers themselves.

Comment: @Event_Horizon, have a quick look at the demos, and see if they match (or are anywhere near matching) your requirements. If not let me know where/how they fail, and I'll see if I can improve them.

Comment: Definitely helpful,thg435 has the shortest code for what I was looking for, but this is good to know as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(card_cost)
{
    card_cost=card_cost.replace(/\d+/g,"<span class='card_costnum' src='numsymbol.png' ></span>");
}
```

Comment: What does putting the plus sign in the regex change? (I haven't had much regex experience)

Comment: The `+` means match the preceding character one or more times.  A `\d` by itself just matches a single digit.  `\d+` matches one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're using jQuery:

```
var theNumbers = card_cost.split(" ");
for (var i=0; i < theNumbers.length; i++) {
    $("#target_div").append("<span class='card_costnum'>"+theNumbers[i]+"</span>");
}
```

I think that achieves something pretty similar to what you're requesting, but I'm not using regex.

Comment: ...why should we assume he's using jQuery? And it looks rather like you're replacing every space-delimited character with the span? Regardless of it being a letter or a number. Or punctuation.

Comment: YOU don't have to in your answer.  It's a condition I'm applying to my answer.  He can add jQuery pretty easily if he's not already, but I don't think it's unreasonable.  If you'd prefer, I can change that to say "add jQuery, then..."

Comment: I don't have a problem with the expression of the assumption, it's the assumption itself that concerns me. Should it be considered valid for people to start answering JavaScript questions with [tag:glow] solutions? How about [tag:mootools]..?

Comment: @DavidThomas, I completely understand that. Sometimes I respond with an approach of how I'd complete something using very similar tools that I know (e.g. an Oracle RDBMS query using syntax I'm *pretty sure* works the same in MySql). I use jQuery, so I utilized that here. But your point is fair.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (card_cost) {
    card_cost = card_cost.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="card_costnum_$1">$1</span>');
}
```

plus CSS like:

```
.card_costnum_42 {
    background-image: url('card_costnum_42.png');
}
```